# Salesforce change the format of created data in apex class

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I have the following apex code that displays the created date of records:

```
for(let i=0; i<emailMessages.length; i++){
replyBody += 'On '+ emailMessages[i].CreatedDate + ' ' + emailMessages[i].From_Name__c +' ' +'responded: ';
}
```

This above code displays the message like this:

> On 2022-06-30T15:27:36.000Z Sarah Kat responded:

I want to change the date format so it can be displayed as below:

> On Thu, Jun 30, 2022 at 4:26 PM Sarah Kat responded:

As there anyway where we can change the date format directly in apex?

Answer (score 1):

Using these docs as my reference:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format
- https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2020/04/format-dates-and-time-using-apex-in.html

[image]

The "format()" function will do what you want. The code would be:

```
Datetime createdDate = Datetime.now();
String converted = createdDate.format('E, MMM d, yyyy K:mm a');
System.debug(converted);
// Sat, Jul 2, 2022 5:21 AM
```

Just change out the Datetime.now() for the CreatedDate of the record you're using.

If you *really* want that specific format, you'll have to do some extra logic to put in the "at" piece. There are probably more elegant ways to do this but this was quick and easy for me to read.

```
Datetime createdDate = Datetime.now();
String converted = createdDate.format('E, MMM d, yyyy K:mm a');
String[] splitup = converted.split(' ');
String final_string = '';
for(Integer i = 0; i < splitup.size(); i++)
{
    // right between year and hour
    if(i == 4)
    {
        final_string = final_string + ' at';
    }

    final_string = final_string + ' ' + splitup[i];
}
System.debug(final_string);
// Sat, Jul 2, 2022 at 5:27 AM
```

**UPDATE**

Yeah, you needed to make the code a function and return the result into what you need. This will work.

```
for(let i=0; i<emailMessages.length; i++){
    replyBody += 'On '+ datetime_formatting_email(emailMessages[i].CreatedDate) + ' ' + emailMessages[i].From_Name__c +' ' +'responded: ';
}

public String datetime_formatting_email(Datetime createdDate)
{
    String converted = createdDate.format('E, MMM d, yyyy K:mm a');
    String[] splitup = converted.split(' ');
    String final_string = '';
        for (Integer i = 0; i < splitup.size(); i++)
        {
            // right between year and hour
            if (i == 4) {
                final_string = final_string + ' at';
            }

            final_string = final_string + ' ' + splitup[i];
        }
    return final_string;
}
```

Comment: I tried the following code but it did not work:

Comment: for(let i=0; i<emailMessages.length; i++){
Datetime createdDate = emailMessages[i].CreatedDate;
String converted = createdDate.format('E, MMM d, yyyy K:mm a');
replyBody += 'On ' + :converted + ' ' + emailMessages[i].From_Name__c +' ' +'wrote: '+ '<br>' +  emailMessages[i].HTML_Body__c + '<br> <br>';
        }

Comment: @shwarmag updated my answer. that should just work for you.